# How to reinstall a snap package?

Tags: software-installation, snap

I would like to reinstall a snap package due to a missing library file (removing and installing the snap again fixed this problem on another system).

How can I avoid the uninstall step (thus preserving my settings) and install again?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unfortunately a command or option to reinstall a snap similar to `apt install --reinstall` does not exist. So removing and then installing the snap again is the only way.

But the settings of the snap will be saved in a snapshot while removing the snap unless you use the `--purge`-option, so just run `snap remove snapname` but not `snap remove --purge snapname`.

Check the snapshot with `snap saved` to see it's ID.

After installing the snap again you can restore the snapshot with `snap restore ID` and your settings are back.

Comment: You're life saver! `snap saved` works even after `snap remove someApp` and then `snap install someApp` ! :) BTW: the "ID" of the snap is in the "Set" column (the first one) of the list you get from `snap saved` - that was super not-obvious for me :)

Comment: Will this download the package again, say for `vscode`? I've to reinstall it without downloading it again due to low data balance. I installed it with `snap` on `ubuntu18.04`.

Comment: @y_159 To download the snap again, you'll have to clear the cache first (sudo rm /var/lib/cache/snapd/*).

Comment: @mook765 i just have to reinstalll it, like in windows you can remove the current installed application, and reinstall from the setup without having to download it again.

Comment: i've to remove the current vscode and reinstall it from same setup in ubuntu.

Comment: @y_159 Then don't clear the cache. Just removing and installing will not attempt to download again.

Comment: so if i use `snap remove code` and then `snap install code`. It will reinstall without downloading again correct?

Comment: @mook765, it was quite confusing. btw thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a command like this:

```
sudo snap remove <package name> && snap install <package name>
```

Because there is no reinstall option in snap package manager, we have to combine uninstall and install commands inorder to perform reinstallation in a single step, eg.:

```
sudo snap remove firefox && snap install firefox
```

Comment: Some explanation and code formatting would be nice

Comment: Also is unclear if that will maintain or restore the package previous settings, as required by the OP.