# How to remove/reinstall core18 snap?

Tags: snap

Snaps are missing. I'd like to reinstall, but I can't seem to remove them first in order to reinstall.  How do I fix this?

```
$ chromium-browser
cannot locate base snap core18: No such file or directory

$ snap list
Name                  Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher    Notes
chromium              87.0.4280.88                1421   latest/stable    canonical✓   -
core                  16-2.48                     10444  latest/stable    canonical✓   core
core18                20200929                    1932   latest/stable    canonical✓   base
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0.20200529             100    latest/stable/…  canonical✓   -
gnome-3-28-1804       3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓   -
gnome-3-34-1804       0+git.3556cb3               60     latest/stable    canonical✓   -
gnome-system-monitor  3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7       148    latest/stable/…  canonical✓   -
gtk-common-themes     0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable/…  canonical✓   -
snap-store            3.38.0-55-geb45541          498    latest/stable/…  canonical✓   -

$ sudo snap install core18
snap "core18" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

$ sudo snap remove core18
error: cannot remove "core18": snap "core18" is not removable: snap is being used by snaps
       chromium, gnome-3-28-1804, gnome-3-34-1804, gnome-system-monitor and 2 more.

$ snap version
snap    2.48+20.04
snapd   2.48+20.04
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.4.0-56-generic
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **Refresh** the snap. If you face an error like

```
snap "core18" has no updates available
```

You can force refresh by switching to edge tracking branch temporarily

```
snap refresh core18 --edge
```

And then, when the problem is fixed, switch it back to stable tracking branch

```
snap refresh core18 --stable
```

Answer (score 1):

[Refreshing](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/snap.1.html) might help:

```
sudo snap refresh core18
```

**`snap help refresh`:**

> The refresh command updates the specified snaps, or all snaps in the system if none are specified.

Answer (score 1):

Removing all the dependencies allows core18 to be removed, then installed again. This wasn't as disruptive as I thought it might be.

My chromium config after Feb 29, 2020 was lost. I specifically made a backup of ~/.config/chromium, but that directory only seemed to include config up to that date.

Comment: The config files for snaps are not in `~/.config` but in `~/snap`. If you remove a snap,  a snapshot will be taken unless you use the `--purge`-option. You should be able to restore a snapshot. You can check for snapshots with `snap saved` and restore with `snap restore ID`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1231238/590937 and `man snap`. The config for chromium you had in `~/.config/chromium` is most likely the config from older chromium version when chromium was still a deb and not a snap.