# Firefox on Ubuntu 21.10 has high CPU usage and will not load sites but other browsers do

Tags: firefox, browser, cpu-load

Firefox was working like a charm until today when it decided to stop working. It was not loading any sites but other browsers could. When running it had high CPU usage but the UI worked normally. I have tried clearing history, cache and data of Firefox but nothing worked. The proposed fixes with fonts didn't work as well as removing the whole common directory from `~/snap/firefox/common`.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox had a problem with a cloud provider or load balancer service that Firefox uses triggering a hang in Firefox's HTTP/3 network code. The change to the cloud provider or load balancer has been reverted and Firefox developers are fixing the networking code.

The problem affected all versions of Firefox on all platforms.

This is all tracked [by this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1749910)

Answer (score -1):

What actually helped me was to reinstall the Firefox. This can be done even without losing data through snap as I learned here [How to reinstall a snap package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198384/how-to-reinstall-a-snap-package). Note: You can not use `--purge` option.

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo snap install firefox
sudo snap saved
sudo snap restore <ID of the snapshot (under Set column)>
```

Comment: Does not work. Also I installed via `apt` so I had to remove and install with apt. Still, same problem.